# finding the derivative of $y=x^2\sqrt{x-1}$

Tags: derivatives

I am working my way through a textbook problem. I have tackled this problem by  using the product rule

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x(x-1)^{1/2} + \frac{1}{2}(x-1)^{-1/2}\times x^2$

However the answer in the textbook is

$x \times (x-1)^{-1/2} \times \frac {5x-4}{2}$

How do I get from my answer to the textbook answer. Is this just a matter of simplifying with algebra?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct. But really, have you not checked it yourself? It is easier than posting the question here.

Comment: Try factoring out the $(x-1)^{-1/2}$

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. Do you mean checking by attempting to simplify myself? I did try checking myself but I got stuck simplifying the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct,just simply $$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x(x-1)^{1/2} + \frac{1}{2}(x-1)^{-1/2}\times x^2=\frac { 4x\left( x-1 \right) +{ x }^{ 2 } }{ 2\sqrt { x-1 }  } =\frac { x\left( 5x-4 \right)  }{ 2\sqrt { x-1 }  } $$

Comment: Might it be a good idea to show the intermittent steps in thus case?

Comment: @i could post,if any steps unclear

Comment: All clear. Thanks. I wasn't treating the exponents properly when I was simplifying.

Answer (score 1):

Factor out $\frac12(x-1)^{-1/2}$ and you get
$$\frac12(x-1)^{-1/2}\bigl(4x(x-1)+x^2\bigr)=\frac12(x-1)^{-1/2}x(4x-4+x).$$
Probably the fastest way to compute it is via logarithmic derivation:
$$\frac{y'}y=\frac 2x+\frac 1{2(x-1)}=\frac{5x-4}{2x(x-1)},\enspace\text{whence}\quad y'=\frac{5x-4}{2x(x-1)}\times x^2\sqrt{x-1}=\dotsm$$

Answer (score 1):

$$y=x^2\sqrt{x-1}=\sqrt{x^5-x^4}=(x^5-x^4)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$y'=\frac{1}{2}(x^5-x^4)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(5x^4-4x^3)=\frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x-1}}\frac{x^2(5x^2-4x)}{2}=???$$